# Is there a way to change the global function in a for loop instead creating a new one?

Tags: python, global-variables

## About the working code

When I run the below codes, I am seeing that they work as expected.

```
def modify_string(n):
    str1 = ", ".join([f"arg{i}" for i in range(n)])
    str2 = f"func{len(str1.split(', ')) - 1}"\
        f"({', '.join(str1.split(', ')[:-1])})"
    return f"lambda {str1}: list(map(lambda i: list({str2})," \
        f" range({str1.split(', ')[-1]})))"


def create_globals(n):
    global func1
    func1 = lambda x: list(map(lambda j: 0, range(x)))
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        globals()[f"func{i}"] = eval(modify_string(i)) 


create_globals(3)
print(func3(3, 2, 4))
```

**Output:**

```
[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

When the `create_globals(n)` function is called, `n` different functions are defined. The names of the functions are changing according to the `i` number. Each created function becomes the argument of the function to be created in the next step:

At the first step of the for loop, the below function is defined:

```
func2 = lambda arg0, arg1: list(map(lambda i: list(func1(arg0)), range(arg1)))
```

At the second step of the for loop, the below function is defined:

```
func3 = lambda arg0, arg1, arg2: list(map(lambda i: list(func2(arg0, arg1)), range(arg2)))
```

So this is a function that creates **n-dimensional matrices**.

## About the question

What I was trying to do is, defining new functions by using the same global name of the function in each step. And at last I wanted to use the last created function. That's why I changed the codes as below:

```
def modify_string(n):
    str1 = ", ".join([f"arg{i}" for i in range(n)])
    str2 = f"func({', '.join(str1.split(', ')[:-1])})"
    return f"lambda {str1}: list(map(lambda i: list({str2})," \
        f" range({str1.split(', ')[-1]})))"


def create_globals(n):
    global func
    func = lambda x: list(map(lambda j: 0, range(x)))
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        globals()["func"] = eval(modify_string(i))
        print("func =", modify_string(i))


create_globals(3)
```

**Output:**

```
func = lambda arg0, arg1: list(map(lambda i: list(func(arg0)), range(arg1)))
func = lambda arg0, arg1, arg2: list(map(lambda i: list(func(arg0, arg1)), range(arg2)))
```

The output seems as expected.
However when I call the function like `func(3, 2, 4)`, I am getting a `TypeError`.

```
func = lambda arg0, arg1: list(map(lambda i: list(func(arg0)), range(arg1)))
func = lambda arg0, arg1, arg2: list(map(lambda i: list(func(arg0, arg1)), range(arg2)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./a.py", line 21, in <module>
    func(2, 3, 4)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg2'
```

Even though I have written `arg2`, the interpreter is reacting as if `arg2` is missing. Can you explain why this is happening?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't provide you exact solution, but didn't you think about recursive realisation?

Comment: No, I didn't think. I thought like that: suppose I defined `globals()["f"] = 1` in the first line. Then I defined `globals()["f"] = 1 + f` in the second line. If I print `f`, the result will be 2. That's why I thought I can do a similar operation like that instead of creating new global variables.

Comment: IMO you should not modify global state in a such way and use data structures (like `list` or `dict`)

Comment: But the first code that I've shared works fine. Why does the second code that I shared raises `TypeError`?

Comment: It's not even worth debugging the monstrosity you are trying to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions find unqualified names that are not local variables by consulting their `globals()`—on *every* access.  (This is how `def current(): return counter` works, of course.)  Each function you create under the single name therefore refers (when called) to the **final** one created, not to any previous incarnation.

This disconnect between construction and execution is one of many reasons not to generate code and `eval` it.  In this case, why not just use a single function with a **variable** number of arguments that calls itself with a prefix of them?

```
def mat(*n):
  return [mat(*n[:-1]) for _ in range(n[-1])] if n else 0
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. In each created function, the previous created function is called. `In this case, why not just use a single function with a variable number of arguments that calls itself with a prefix of them?` According to the code I wrote, to generate `n` dimensional matris function,` (n - 1)` amount of functions need to be created. Because every function calls the previous function. Can you please give me an example about the approach you suggested? (By the way do you think what you did ask, is related to the first code I shared?)

Comment: @dildeolupbiten: No, in **every** function created, the call is to the **same** one most recently created before the **call**.